# Keras custom loss function using outputs of each neuron

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, layer, loss-function

I am trying to custom a loss function using the outputs of each neuron of the last layer. And the function may not be linear. Here is what I am working on:

```
## some previous layers##
## my last dense layer##
dense1 = Dense(4, activation="relu", name="dense_layer1")(previous layer)


dense11 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "dense11")(dense1)
dense12 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "dense12")(dense1)
dense13 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "dense13")(dense1)
dense14 = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "dense14")(dense1)


## custom loss function ##

def custom_layer(tensor):
    return tensor[1]*2+tensor[2]+tensor[3]/(tensor[4]*2)  #some nonlinear function like this


lambda_layer = Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer")([dense11,dense12,dense13,dense14])

model = Model(inputs=Input, outputs=lambda_layer)  # "Input" are in previous layers, not shown here

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=512, verbose=1)
```

My Y_train is n*1 (n is the sample size).

So I am basically applying a nonlinear transformation of those final four neurons' output, which is equivalent as to construct a new loss function. After the transformation, the y hat should also be a n*1 vector.

But the code keeps not working. I think it is due to the lambda_layer or the custom_layer function. I also tried to define a new loss function (then there would be no "lambda_layer"), but it didn't work either. I have no idea what's wrong with it. (headache!)

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated!! Thanks a lot! (I'm using Python3.7 with Tensorflow version 2.0.0)

---

Solved, thanks!

Comment: what does it mean the operator ^ ? Do you mean instead ** (3**2 = 9)

Comment: Yes! I mean "**", but actually when I run the code I just added four outputs together (a linear).

Comment: The error I got shows up as: 
``` IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thanks for the comment! I modified the loss function and added a new part "update #1".

Comment: @Doi_Ann remembers that in python the indexing starts from 0. so in your case is tensor[0]*2+tensor[1]+tensor[2]/(tensor[3]*2) and not tensor[1]*2+tensor[2]+tensor[3]/(tensor[4]*2)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Oh yes! This is a stupid mistake! I'll modify the code and rerun it. Thanks a lot!